# Cannot exclude C1.WPF.4.dll. from dependencies and installer project

Tags: windows, vb.net, windows-installer, .net-assembly

We have a Vb.net project which is using `C1.WPF.4.dll` assembly.
When we create an installer project `C1.WPF.4.dll` dependency gets added to the project and installer.

1. We tried to exclude C1.WPF.4.dll from the main project.
2. Tried to remove the reference from dependency and VDPROJ file
3. C1.WPF.4.dll has dependencies of .net framework.
4. all other dlls can be excluded but only this dll is unable to exclude.

But if we rebuild the project the dll still appears in the installer project.

How can we exclude or remove dll from the installer project?

thanks in advance.

We are using Visual Studio 2017 to create the installer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3HLA.png

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many reasons I don't recommend using Visual Studio Deployment Projects (.VDPROJ).  I spent years trying to turn off this automated dependency scanning.  It's impossible really.

Check out Windows Installer XML (WiX - opensource) and Industrial Strength Windows Installer XML (IsWiX - opensource by me).  I have a tutorial here:

https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials